# Unknown tcp states being returned by MSFT_NetTCPConnection CIM Query

Tags: .net, wmi, wmi-query

**Overview**

The method below queries the [MSFT_NetTCPConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/nettcpipprov/msft-nettcpconnection) CIM instance and returns a list of TCP Connections on the target machine. This is the CIM instance that underlies the powershell [Get-NetTCPConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps) command.

**Problem**

I noticed that I get some instances back that report back a TCP state id 100, which is [undocumented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/nettcpipprov/msft-nettcpconnection) as far as I can tell. What does this status mean? My guess is that these are dead connections and I can probably filter them out but I'm hoping someone out there might know the answer to this.

```cs
public const string TcpConnectionNamespace = Wmi.StandardCimv2Namespace;
public const string TcpConnectionClassName = "MSFT_NetTCPConnection";
public const string ProcessIdKey = "OwningProcess";
public const string LocalAddressKey = "LocalAddress";
public const string LocalPortKey = "LocalPort";
public const string RemoteAddressKey = "RemoteAddress";
public const string RemotePortKey = "RemotePort";
public const string StateKey = "State";

public IEnumerable<TcpConnectionModel> GetTcpConnections()
{
    var session = CimSession.Create(Server);
    var instances = session.QueryInstances(
        TcpConnection.TcpConnectionNamespace,
        Wmi.QueryDialect,
        $"Select * From {TcpConnection.TcpConnectionClassName}");

    foreach (var instance in instances)
    {
        var processId = Convert.ToUInt32(instance.CimInstanceProperties[TcpConnection.ProcessIdKey].Value);
        yield return new TcpConnectionModel()
        {
            ProcessId = processId,
            ProcessName = _processService.GetProcessFromPid(processId).ProcessName,
            LocalAddress = IPAddress.Parse(instance.CimInstanceProperties[TcpConnection.LocalAddressKey].Value.ToString()),
            LocalPort = Convert.ToUInt16(instance.CimInstanceProperties[TcpConnection.LocalPortKey].Value.ToString()),
            RemoteAddress = IPAddress.Parse(instance.CimInstanceProperties[TcpConnection.RemoteAddressKey].Value.ToString()),
            RemotePort = Convert.ToUInt16(instance.CimInstanceProperties[TcpConnection.RemotePortKey].Value.ToString()),
            State = TcpConnection.ConvertState(Convert.ToInt32(instance.CimInstanceProperties[TcpConnection.StateKey].Value))
        };
    }
}
```

**TCP States**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found state 100 in "Get-NetTCPConnection" output on Win Server 2008. Compared to the output on Win10 for the same command, it seems to mean "bound".

**Output**

(LocalAddress = 0.0.0.0, LocalPort = [high port] RemoteAddress = 0.0.0.0, RemotePort = 0, State = Bound, AppliedSetting = [not shown], ...)

There is also a Cmdlet definition XML on your machine that you can check. "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetTCPIP\MSFT_NetTCPConnection.cdxml" (search for NetTCPConnection.State to get the enum values).

Comment: I suppose I could have mentioned in my question that I’m running Windows 10 1809 on my workstation. I haven’t tested this out on any other machines.

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: You can see it in the Cmdlet definition XML on your machine. 
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\NetTCPIP\MSFT_NetTCPConnection.cdxml" (search for NetTCPConnection.State to get the enum values).  These will give the values assigned to the state enums documented here... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=win10-ps

Comment: Wow I never would have known about that. Thanks!